# Ошибка при выполнение запроса VK API

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Добрый вечер! 
Не понимаю, в чем может быть ошибка при выполнение запроса на редактирование объявления через API VK. 
Выдает вот такую вот ошибку:

```
Array ( 
  [error] => Array ( 
     [error_code] => 100 
     [error_msg] => One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: data[ad_id] is invalid [request_params]
  )
)
```

Параметры беру верные, но почему-то не нравится data[ad_id]
Вот так выглядит часть кода передающего data[ad_id]

```
$data = array(
        'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
        'account_id'   => 1602129376,
        'data'         => json_encode(array(
            'ad_id'  => 32266445,
            'name' => '111',
        ))
    );
```

### Решение проблемы:

Ответила поддержка ВК. Нужно параметры передавать сразу в JSON, то есть с использованием json_encode не работает. 
В итоге передача параметров выглядит вот так:

```
$json = '[{"ad_id":32266445,"name":111}]';
$data = array(
        'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
        'account_id'   => 1602129376,
        'data'         => $json);
```

Всем большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Какой метод API используете? Так точно ничем не поможем

Comment: ads.updateAds, вероятно. У меня в рабочих записях полугодовой давности есть примечание, что настройку какого-нибудь (любого, но хотя бы одного) таргетинга надо передавать всегда, даже если его менять не планировали. Попробуйте указать что-нибудь из таргетингов.

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan  Вот полный код https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1bc57815ce915f17ca0af30da654ac78

Comment: @Мелкий Хорошо, спасибо попробую. А поделиться рабочими записями для редактирования объявления можете?:)

Comment: Остальные путевые заметки именно по объявлениям: совершенно невразумительные сообщения об ошибках, из которых неясно, что вообще этому вк не нравится. Надо внимательно смотреть в свой запрос и пытаться угадать, что же тут не так. Возраст строго число между 14 и 80, другие значения вернут эту невразумительную ошибку. Неверно описанные в документации размеры изображений уже исправили. Вроде бы по объявлениям всё.

Comment: @Мелкий Хорошо, спасибо большое. Написал в поддержку ВК. Буду очень признателен, если кто-то сталкивался с подобными проблемами и подскажет решения. Как только разберусь в чем именно была проблема - отпишусь.

Comment: Ответила поддержка ВК. Решение оказалось простое. 
"Попробуйте в data передать вручную
[{"ad_id":32266445,"name":'111}]"
Не понятно почему не работает через json_encode, задал им этот вопрос. 
Массив с параметрами выглядит вот так: 
$json = '[{"ad_id":32266445,"name":111}]';
$data = array(
        'access_token' => $token['access_token'],
        'account_id'   => 1602129376,
        'data'         => $json);

Answer (score 0):

Ага, ну да, логично. Не обратил внимания.

Ваш запрос рабочий с подстановкой JSON строкой:

```
$json = '[{"ad_id":32266445,"name":111}]';
```

А теперь разбираемся, почему он оказался рабочий. Для этого распакуем его обратно через `json_decode` и распечатаем в виде PHP-кода через `var_export`:

```
$json = '[{"ad_id":32266445,"name":111}]';
var_export(json_decode($json, true));
```

Получим

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'ad_id' => 32266445,
    'name' => 111,
  ),
)
```

Ну вот и очевидный ответ - в `data` должен быть массив описаний объявлений, а у вас - сразу описание объявления. В PHP числовой массив и ассоциативный - одна и та же вещь, поэтому ошибка сразу в глаза не бросается.

Выводите детали запроса как можно ближе к непосредственному запросу, как уже будут отправлены по сети, а не как эти данные строятся.

Answer (score 0):

**Вот так у меня срабатывает**

```
$data = [
       "ad_id" => $ad_id,
       "description" => $description
    ];

$this->api('ads.updateAds', [
            'account_id'   => $account_id,
            'data'   => json_encode([$data]),
        ]);
```